# CSS Flexbox: grow first flex items instead of last ones

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-boxes layout that grows the boxes in the final "row", like here:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q43ae.png)

The CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: inline-block;

    position: relative; width: 14em; height: 14em; min-width: 14em;
}
```

**The question:** can one indicate in such a `row` flow to preferably grow the "first" flex-items rather than the "last" ones (via CSS not JS)?

Comment: add your HTML code so we can edit it for you. put all code in a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; in the container class, and in your html add the elements in reverse order

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! That did it for me, though I also had to `row-reverse` in addition to `wrap-reverse`. Merci Mr. Stash!